# How to detect when admin modifies User in Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I use Django's User models for both admins and normal users. Sometimes admins need to do manual modifications to user accounts, for example change e-mail or disable some account. These modifications are done from the basic admin panel that comes with Django.

The question is, how can I detect these modification events? I need this for making some log entries and doing other stuff.

I already tried pre_save signal of User, and that can be used to detect what fields will change, but the problem is I have no clue where that save() originates from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model is saved in the [`ModelAdmin.save_model()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) method.

You can unregister the default admin for the `User` model and register with your own `ModelAdmin` with overriden `save_model()`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # do whatever you want.
        # obj - the User instance to change
        # request.user - admin
        obj.save()


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check whether a field has changed in the `save_model` method by inspecting `form.changed_data`. This is a list of the names of the fields which have changed. Below is a small code

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if 'parking_location' in form.changed_data:
        messages.info(request, "Parking location has changed")
    else:
        messages.info(request, "Parking location has not changed")
    super(MyVehiclesAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```